# Views - how to display a column showing who made the last update

Tags: views, users

I'm updating the main content2 view, and I'd like to add another column to show which user made the last update. I'm using workbench moderation, in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit your content type's Publishing options & enable 'Create new revision'.
2. In Views' Advanced pane, add a Relationship of type 'Content revision: User'.
3. Under Fields, add the field 'User: Name' AND use the relationship you just created.

Voilà!

Comment: Merci! I was almost there. Works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning)
2. In your view fields section you will now find a new option called **Content: Last edited by**